# Unable to uninstall anaconda from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04, uninstallation

I am trying to uninstall Ananconda from my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine.

I ran the following commands

```
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean
rm -rf ~/anaconda
```

Everything is getting exceuted without any error/warning. If fact, when I run `anaconda-clean` it is saying so and so packages have been uninstalled. However, I can still open up anaconda navigator and everything seems to be working just fine. What am I missing?

Comment: How do you "open anaconda"? Anaconda is not a program.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I mean anaconda-navigator.
Edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Type `which conda` to get the location of the `conda` binary. You can also install `locate`, e.g: `apt-get install locate` then do `sudo updatedb` then `locate conda` to get the location of those files.

Comment: Okay, I have the location of conda. Then do I manually delete those files? If so, will that completely uninstall anaconda for me? I am not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean --yes
rm -rf ~/anaconda3
```

Replace *anaconda3* with your version of anaconda

This will uninstall anaconda